# How to parse xmlString with jquery without ajax call?

Tags: xml, jquery, xml-parsing

I want to parse xmlString with jquery but without using ajax call ?

**xmlString =**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <root>  
            <item id="4" parent_id="0" state="close">  
                <content><name>Charles Madigen</name></content>                
            </item>  
            <item id="192" parent_id="4" state="close">    
          <content><name>Ralph Brogan</name></content>  

            </item> 
         </root>
```

I want to parse above xml for IDs?
4 , 192.... How to parese xmlString with jquery.

[Xml parsing with jquery+ ajax call](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery)

In my case I dont have any xml file ex. a.xml

On some operation I got xmlString which I want to parse for ID

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```js
var xmlString = '<xml><some myAttr="1">test</some></xml>';
var xmlDOM = $.parseXML(xmlString);
$(xmlDOM).find('some').attr('myAttr') // yields "1"
```

In other words, you can treat your XML string as usual DOM structure, and use any jQuery selectors and methods.

As for your example, code will look like this:

```js
var xmlDOM = $.parseXML(xmlString);
var items = $(xmlDOM).find('root item');
$.each (items, function(key, val){
    alert ($(val).attr('id'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply  $(xmlString).find('item').attr('id') returns only one(1st id=4). I want to all ID 4,192... . and above example not working :(

Comment: sorry, updated above script to correctly iterate through all items :)